# What is the use of request.referer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to know what the following code does. What is the use of `request.referer`?

```
@board = request.referer['dashboard'] if request.referer
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`request.referer` gives you the previous URL or `/` if none. It is usually used to redirect the user back to the previous page ([link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/131-going-back?view=comments))

More information [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Request/referer)

Regarding your question, it is simply returning `'dashboard'` if found in `request.referer`. Look at the following example:

```
> str = "hello world!"
 => "hello world!"
> str['hello']
 => "hello"
> str['lo wo']
 => "lo wo"
> str['foo']
 => nil
```

However, you should not depend on this method to redirect your user back. You can do this in your controller instead:

```
redirect_to :back
```

Comment: But don't always depend on request.referer to go back. In many cases it returns nil and breaks the code.

Comment: I will look at it @RSB, did not have time yesterday ;)

Comment: try `redirect_to(request.referrer || root_path)`

Answer (score 1):

request.referer gives you the previous URL or `/` if none

In library you can see:

```
def referer    
  @env['HTTP_REFERER'] || '/'
end
```

You can use the referer technique for this, but you'll have to capture it when entering the form instead of when the form is submitted. Something like this:

`<%= hidden_field_tag :referer, (params[:referer] || request.env['HTTP_REFERER']) %>`

Then you can use `params[:referer]` in the controller to `redirect back`.